# Determining order of windows opened

Tags: c#, c++, windows, visual-studio, windows-xp

Through the windows API I can get the list of all windows which are currently open but it seems that the IntPtr's don't come back in any specific order. I was wondering if there is a way to get the windows in the order in which they were opened. For instance if I open 2 IE windows followed by a notepad window, when I retrieve the list of windows I would like the 2 IE windows to be before the notepad window. I am doing this in C#.

Comment: What API call are you using to return the list of Windows?

Comment: If your app is running while the windows are opened then you could install a hook which is called whenever a window is opened and keep track of things yourself.

Comment: Curious why you would want to know?

Comment: Well I'm writing some testing software and we need to be able to assert foreground windows but someone requested that we check because if multiple windows are open with the same name they want to assert that the 2nd one opened is the currently focused window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle values are obfuscated pointers, you cannot rely on their value at all.  And they get recycled.

The long distance shot is GetWindowThreadProcessId() to get the ID of the thread that owns the window.  OpenThread() to get a handle to it.  GetThreadTimes() to find out when that thread was created.  CloseHandle() to clean up.  The result is however but a guesstimate, do avoid wanting to ask such a question.  Visit pinvoke.net for the declarations.

Comment: It's funny that this works for just about every application except for FireFox it seems that all the firefox windows are spawned off the same thread (but I wrote a work around for that)